# How to read microsoft outlook items in .net

Tags: .net, outlook-addin

I have a Autonomy/Imanage which is a document management system application integrated in Microsoft outlook which provides the result in a separate mail items section in columns like title,version of document, author etc. I want to read those items in table's format.

Can I read those items on the basis of column name rows?
In my analysis , it cannot be done because these items are custom rows and column and not part of outlook.ineterope dll.

Please let me know if there is a way to read those items?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using IMAP. This will also loosely couple your application to your mail server as IMAP is a standard protocol where as Outlook/Exchange format is proprietary.